# Why the error "the trait `FnOnce<()>` is implemented but that implementation is not `const`"?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust. I'm using rust 1.60.0.

I'm trying to use this code ([PLAYGROUND HERE](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=pub%20const%20VERSION%3A%20%26%27static%20str%20%3D%20option_env!(%22VERSION%22).unwrap_or_else(%7C%7C%20%22dev%22)%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22Hello%2C%20world!%22)%3B%0A%7D)):

```rust
pub const VERSION: &'static str = option_env!("VERSION").unwrap_or_else(|| "dev");
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
the trait bound `[closure@src\constants.rs:4:81: 4:89]: ~const FnOnce<()>` is not satisfied
the trait `~const FnOnce<()>` is not implemented for `[closure@src\constants.rs:4:81: 4:89]`
wrap the `[closure@src\constants.rs:4:81: 4:89]` in a closure with no arguments: `|| { /* code */ }`rustcE0277
constants.rs(4, 66): the trait `FnOnce<()>` is implemented for `[closure@src\constants.rs:4:81: 4:89]`, but that implementation is not `const`
option.rs(797, 12): required by a bound in `Option::<T>::unwrap_or_else`
```

Can you help me understand what's wrong with it?

Comment: The errors aren't great, but you have two problems. First, you can't really use closures in const expressions (yet), and second, `unwrap_or_else` is not (yet) const either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

const is meant for compile time evaluation, not all functions can be evaluated at compile time, which is why it is requiring a const FnOnce but const FnOnce are limited, you can learn more here of what can be evaluated compile time:
https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html
In your case, even if you use a const fn you'll still get the error:

```
error: `Option::<T>::unwrap_or_else` is not yet stable as a const fn
```

as that function itself can't be called at compile time.
What you can do is use the match expression which can be evaluated compile time:

```
pub const VERSION: &'static str = match option_env!("VERSION") {
    Some(version) => version,
    None => "dev",
};
```